# MS PowerPivot - Subtotals (not grand totals) for Metrics

Tags: excel, business-intelligence, powerpivot, dax

Sorry for the vague title.

I have used "Σ Values" and another field as row labels. The columns are time periods (weeks, months and years). The table is populated with a number of basic metrics (e.g., sums).

How do I show row subtotals for each of the metrics? I have only been able to add grand totals, but they end up at the bottom.

Additionally, how do I expand / collapse the metrics so they only show the metric subtotal?

I am happy to send a picture, but I can't post it because I do not have a high enough reputation.

THANKS!!

Answer (score 0):

From the PowerPivot window, click the Pivot table button to create a new pivot table. Then drag fields to the row and column areas. Drag measures to the values area.

You can turn on/off sub-totals for each row or column. Right click in any cell and set your desired option in the context menu.

If that does not help, edit your question and provide more detail. You might consider using one of the gazillion free file sharing services and post a link to an image or sample data set.